# How to use ng-animate dynamically

Tags: angularjs

I have two simple container, 1st one contain a directive, when I click on it the directive will fire function and inside that function I want to dynamically add and remove ng-animate on other contianer which should become active and inactive on condition

```
<div class="form-group">
         <div>
            <yesno-button class="radioField" show-hide ng-click="showChildFields(ev)"></yesno-button>
            <label class="radio-inline control-label">1st Container</label>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
        <div>
            <yesno-button class="radioField"></yesno-button>
            <label class="radio-inline control-label">2nd Container</label>
        </div>
</div>
```

I have a show-hide directive define

```
module.directive("showHide", function () {

    return {


        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {

            scope.showChildFields = function (ev) {
                    //need to enable and disbale 2nd container with ng-animation
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired effect with [`ng-show`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow).  Set a boolean variable when the first `yesno-button` is clicked.  Then use `ng-show` to display the second container when that variable is true.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div>
    <input type="button" ng-click="container.showChildren = !container.showChildren" value="Yes/No"/>
    <label class="radio-inline control-label">
      1st Container
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group animate-show" ng-show="container.showChildren">
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Yes/No"/>
    <label class="radio-inline control-label">
      2nd Container
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice that the second container has the class `animate-show` so that animations will be applied.

Here is a demo, adapted from the `ng-show` api documentation: http://plnkr.co/WdQ4Y1ARxsWkUhEf7pA1

Comment: I added the animate-show class but not getting that effect when I click on the button.Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you also add the ng-show, binding to the variable set by ng-click?

Comment: Yes, ng-show working properly,it show hide element on click..But not getting animation effect.

Comment: Oh, did you add the relevant css?  Look at the css file in the plunker for the style definitions.

Comment: Yes, I added the style as well. But no luck

Comment: Can you send me a link to your plunker?

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to integrate it into my project..I simply added the related style into my css file..I already had ng-click event on required button which toggle the binding that is handling with ng-show directive like you did in the sample..

Comment: Last question. Have you included angular-animate.js?

Comment: Did you remove `style="display:none;"` from the second form group?  it could interfere with the animation.

Comment: yes, did everything to make it work..But it's not reacting how I am wondering.. Don't know what's going wrong

Comment: well, i highly recommend getting it to work outside your project as a small plunker or fiddle.  only after it works there, splice it into the main project.  if you get a little demo going, please update the question so we can help.